# stacked and stationary objects

Tags: forces, gravity

Say two boxes are stacked on top of each other, resting on the ground. Box A is on the bottom and box B is on top. Is the force the ground exerts on box A greater than the force box A exerts on box B?

I think that yes, because the force the ground exerts upon A is equal to A + B, but the force A exerts on B is only equal to B. Is that right?

Comment: I think that you got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

Let's break it down.

**Forces acting on box B:**

Gravity = $-m_Bg$

Normal force from box A pushing up on box B = $m_Bg$

We know these must be opposite and equal since the net force on B is 0 (because there is no net acceleration if it is stationary.)

**Forces acting on Box A:**

Gravity = $-m_Ag$

Box B pushing on Box A = $-m_Bg$

Thus, the force the ground exerts on box A must balance these two forces if box A is to be stationary (no net force).  Therefore,

Normal force from ground on box A = $g(m_A + m_B)$

Therefore it is clear that the ground exerts more force on box A than box A exerts on box B.